# How can I access the HTTPContext in a class derived from PageModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In order to simplify the handling of the session variables in my Razor page, I would like to insert a separate class between the PageModel and the IndexModel.

PageModel <- MyPageModel <- IndexModel

Now I notice that in the classes MyPageModel and IndexModel the HTTPContext is defined but not set (=null).
However, if I derive the class IndexModel directly from the class PageModel, everything is fine and I can access the HTTPContext and the session variables.
The settings in Startup are fine so far, as the rest of the pages work fine.
What am I doing wrong? Or have I overlooked something?

Class MyPageModel derived from PageModel

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApp.Areas.Ansicht12.Pages
{
    public class MyPageModel : PageModel
    {
        string s1 = default;
        string s2 = default;
        int i3 = 0;

        public MyPageModel() : base()
        {
            s1 = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Var-1");
            s2 = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Var-2");
            i3 = (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Var-3");
        }

    }
}`
```

Class IndexModel derived from MyPageModel

```
namespace WebApp.Areas.Ansicht12.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : MyPageModel
    {
        public IndexModel() : base()
        {
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you could pass in the context...  but why would this make getting session variables any easier?  What's the use-case for these session variables?  (Seems like these should be avoided as much as possible...)

Comment: Hi @Giuliano Casagrande, your code seems not match what you said.  I cannot see anywhere you set the session variables, but you read the session in `MyPageModel `. Is your requirement to access HttpContext in `IndexModel` which is derived from `MyPageModel`? Where did you set the session variable?

Comment: @ pcalkins - The use case is actually quite simple. I want to set certain values in a view and retrieve them a little later. This also works well if the IndexModel is derived directly from the PageModel.
The hint with the context seems very interesting to me. How can I pass on the context of the derived class? I am still a little weak on this point.

Comment: @Rena - The session variables are set in a separate place. I didn't want to overload my post with code. Here is the code where the session variables are set:

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApp.Areas.Ansicht12.Pages
{
    public class Index1Model : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Var-1", "Jupiter");
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Var-2", "Zeus");
            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Var-3", 6554321);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: (sorry, I'm still struggling a bit with the editor)

Comment: You should include what the variables are used for...  (why are they expiring with the session?  why they aren't persisted in other ways... database, cookies not tied to session, passed from page to page in view models, etc...)  I'm still not sure why you need another class for this.  Just get the session vars when you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpContext is not available when the constructor of the Razor pages is called. You could use `IHttpContextAccessor` to meet your requirement.

MyPageModel:

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
{
    string s1 = default;
    string s2 = default;
    int i3 = 0;
    public MyPageModel(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) :base()    
    {
        s1 = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Var-1");
        s2 = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Var-2");
        i3 = (int)httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Var-3");
    }            
}
```

IndexModel :

```
public class IndexModel: MyPageModel
{
    public IndexModel(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(httpContextAccessor)
    {
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Be sure register the service in `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Now it works. Thank you.